# My app won't load when I bring in a MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a simple number guessing game. At the moment I have it set that when you guess the correct number it takes you to WinActivity.java. All I want it to do on that screen is say "You won" and to play a little trumpet victory sound (and also display a button that'll bring them to the GameActivity if they want to play again).

The trouble is, when I try bringing in a MediaPlayer the app doesn't even start.

Here is my code for my WinActivity that contains the MediaPlayer.

```
package com.example.jeremy.numberguessinggame;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WinActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_win);

    MediaPlayer trumpetsound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.trumpet);
    trumpetsound.start();

    Button btnPlayAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    TextView youWon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewYouWon);

    btnPlayAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent playAgainIntent = new Intent(WinActivity.this,GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(playAgainIntent);

        }
    });

}
}
```

When I run the app the Messages Gradle Build window will pop up and says "error: cannot find symbol variable raw".

I added the raw folder to the res location, and was able to drag the sounds into the folder no problem.

I just don't see why I can't make this MediaPlayer work.

I would love some help. If you need more information I'll be glad to give it to you.

Comment: does your "trumpet" file inside your `raw` folder have a valid extension? Like `trumpet.mp3` for example?

Comment: It does have .mp3 by it. Here is an image: http://i.imgur.com/AwNwsrw.png

Comment: have you tried doing a `clean`and rebuild?

Comment: Ooh! Rebuilding it worked! Thanks a lot, man! Does that mean that I messed something up slightly? I'd just like to know if it was likely something that I caused somehow.

Comment: can't say for sure what the root cause is. i get the same behavior from time-to-time with various libraries that do code generation. when in doubt, just trying cleaning + rebuilding.